# EventListener work only once

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, event-listener

I have this HTML code,

```
<input type='button' id='addQuestion' class='btn' value='Add Question'/>
```

and a JavaScript Code,

```
var question;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var aQ = document.getElementById("addQuestion");
    aQ.addEventListener("click",addQ);
});

function addQ(){
question = question + 1;
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<div>question</div>";
}
```

It supposed to be able to create more than one div.
I tried to use onclick instead of EventListener,

```
<input type='button' id='addQuestion' class='btn' onclick="addQ()" value='Add Question'/>
```

and it is working.

Comment: any errors in console ?

Comment: there is no error in console.

Comment: by the way, i put the script after <head> tag and before <body> tag.

Comment: the second way should work, can you add a fiddle?

Comment: what second way? the onclick? Can I do it using EventListener?

Comment: Are you overriding the button when you set the innerHTML of content?

Comment: I think yes. The button is inside of "Menu" div, then menu div is in side the "content" div.

Comment: this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7jjh16s/) is working using the code above

Comment: this jsBin works http://jsbin.com/zuqati/1/edit?html,console,output

Comment: @ dvhh and Roko C . your codes are working. But when i tried to put the button inside the content div, it is only once. What is the best way to solve it without changing html code?

Comment: @roko and dvhh, I changed the html code and put the button outside the Content div. It works. Thanks to your comments and answers.

Answer (score 1):

Some minor changes (***[demo](http://jsbin.com/zuqati/1/edit?html,console,output)***):

```
    var question = 0; // init as typeof Number 

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        var aQ = document.getElementById("addQuestion");
        aQ.addEventListener("click",addQ);
    });

    function addQ(){
        question = question + 1;
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<div>"+question+"</div>"; 
        //                                    Use the variable--^^^^^^^^
    }
```

Comment: I don't need to make it a number. :). But thanks. And also, I change the html code and put the button outside the Content div. It works. Thanks to your comments and answer.